# Rails: Errors close to particular fields in forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I am trying to add some errors to a form close to the field that caused the error and here is how I am doing this:

```
 <%= lesson_form.text_field :description %><br />
  <% unless @lesson.errors[:description].blank? %>
    <span id="error_explanation">
      Description <%= @lesson.errors[:description].join(", ") %>
    </span>
  <% end -%>

  <%= lesson_form.label :category %>
  <%= lesson_form.text_field :category %><br />
  <% unless @lesson.errors[:category].blank? %>
    <span id="error_explanation">
      Category <%= @lesson.errors[:category].join(", ") %>
    </span>
  <% end -%>
```

I would like to know if there is a better an non repetitive way of doing this.  As you see I am repeating the same unless errors... for each of the fields.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a helper method:

```
def errors_for(model, attribute)
  if model.errors[attribute].present?
    content_tag :span, :class => 'error_explanation' do
      model.errors[attribute].join(", ")
    end
  end
end
```

And in view:

```
<%= lesson_form.text_field :description %><br />
  <%= errors_for @lesson, :description %>

  <%= lesson_form.label :category %>
  <%= lesson_form.text_field :category %><br />
  <%= errors_for @lesson, :category %>
<% end %>
```

Or you could use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) which will do it all for you like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @lesson do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :category %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

And if you use simple_form and [haml](http://haml-lang.com/), things look a bit neater:

```
= simple_form_for @lesson do |f|
  = f.input :description
  = f.input :category
  = f.button :submit
```

The above will show the error next to the field and will detect type of the attribute and show the appropriate input box (eg text, password, checkbox etc.), all with one simple line `f.input`.

Comment: Started using simple form. Seems awesome. Thanks

Comment: The helper method example has a typo, it should be model.errors[ not mode.errors[